# Crop image before setting as a wallpaper and share that on facebook?

Tags: android, facebook

```
      public class FullImageActivity extends Activity {
    Button share;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.full_image);
          Button buttonSetWallpaper = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
          share=(Button)findViewById(R.id.share);
        // get intent data
        Intent i = getIntent();

        // Selected image id
        final int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
        final ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);
        buttonSetWallpaper.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                  WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager 
                    = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                    try {
                        myWallpaperManager.setResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);
                        Toast.makeText(FullImageActivity.this, "wallpaper changed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    }
            });
        share.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String url = "https://www.facebook.com/";
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

I want to crop images when user set that image as a wallpaper. How can i do this, and i also want to share that image on facebook, I tried to apply share code for facebook but it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Below given is class to crop photo from gallery while selecting it from Gallery!Hoe it will help you.

```
 package com.tag.photocaptureandgallery;

 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
 import java.io.FileOutputStream;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.OutputStream;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.app.AlertDialog;
 import android.content.DialogInterface;
 import android.content.Intent; 
 import android.database.Cursor;
 import android.graphics.Bitmap;
 import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
 import android.net.Uri;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.os.Environment;
 import android.provider.MediaStore;
 import android.provider.MediaStore.MediaColumns;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.ImageView;

  public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private final int SELECT_FILE = 1;
private final int REQUEST_CAMERA = 0;
private ImageView ivImage;
private Button btnSetImage;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ivImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
    btnSetImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSelectPhoto);

    btnSetImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            selectImage();
        }
    });

}

private void selectImage() {
    final CharSequence[] items = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Library",
            "Cancel" };

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                File f = new File(android.os.Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
            } else if (items[item].equals("Choose from Library")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                                   intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
                intent.putExtra("outputX", 512);
                intent.putExtra("outputY", 512);
                intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
                intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
                intent.putExtra("scale", true);
                startActivityForResult(
                        Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),
                        SELECT_FILE);
            } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {
            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .toString());
            for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {
                if (temp.getName().equals("temp.jpg")) {
                    f = temp;
                    break;
                }
            }
            try {
                Bitmap bm;
                BitmapFactory.Options btmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

                bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(),
                        btmapOptions);

                // bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, 70, 70, true);
                ivImage.setImageBitmap(bm);

                String path = android.os.Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + File.separator
                        + "Phoenix" + File.separator + "default";
                f.delete();
                OutputStream fOut = null;
                File file = new File(path, String.valueOf(System
                        .currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
                try {
                    fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut);
                    fOut.flush();
                    fOut.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

            String tempPath = getPath(selectedImageUri, MainActivity.this);
            Bitmap bm;
            BitmapFactory.Options btmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(tempPath, btmapOptions);
            ivImage.setImageBitmap(bm);
        }
    }
}

public String getPath(Uri uri, Activity activity) {
    String[] projection = { MediaColumns.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = activity
            .managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}

  }
```

Comment: If my solution has benefitted you then please accept or vote up my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to crop image taken from gallery or camera?
Android provides feature to crop the image while selecting from gallery or clicking from 
Camera!

Comment: sir i want to crop image from gallarey and i have taken 50+images in gridview.when i select any image i want to set that image as a wallpaper,before setting i want  to crop that...

Comment: @jgar pandya sir..my image s are not cropping which i am seleting from gridview...:(

Comment: My code will crop image while you are selecting it from Gallery.Like in facebook and whatspp.

Comment: ya its working..,but i want to crop my gridimages whcih iscoming from gridview

Comment: Have a look at this tutorial - http://karanbalkar.com/2012/10/tutorial-9-working-with-images-in-android/